# Regex to strip Drive letter

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to check if there is a `letter` followed by `colon` in my string.

If so, strip both.

`F:/users/mark/` => `/users/mark/`

This is what I have so far:

```
if(Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]:", path))
        path = path.substring(2);
```

Does anyone have a better idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Use the following "^[a-zA-Z]:" which means you start with your drive letter followed by colon.

Comment: `path = path.replaceFirst("^[a-zA-Z]:", "");`

Comment: `matches` doesn't try to check if some substring may match regex, but if *entire* string will match it. You need to add `.*` at the end of regex to let it match rest of string, or use `Matcher.find()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
path = path.replaceAll("^[a-zA-Z]:", "");
```

Comment: @Angelina I am almost sure  you put the regex into `matches`. Don't. Just use `path = path.replaceFirst("^[a-zA-Z]:", "");`

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex `^[^\/]*(.*)` and capture the first group.

```
sourceString = sourceString.replaceAll("^[^\\/]*(.*)", "$1");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pW2jE5/1)

**Input**

```
F:/users/mark/
```

**Matched Info**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [2-14]  `/users/mark/`
```

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve your goal with simple string methods:

```
String path = "F:/some/path";
if (path.length() > 1 && Character.isLetter(path.charAt(0)) && path.charAt(1) == ':') {
    path = path.substring(2);
    System.out.println(path); // this is for demo
}
```

See [Java demo](https://ideone.com/EiBLDF)

Where:

- `path.length() > 1` - If `path` length more than 1
- `&& Character.isLetter(path.charAt(0))` - and the first char is a letter
- `&& path.charAt(1) == ':'` - and the second char is `:`,
- `path.substring(2)` - use the substring beginning from the 2nd index.

Yes, do not forget to assign the result to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but thought I'd throw in what worked for me.

```
String path = "F:\\some\\path";
if(path.matches("^[a-zA-Z]:.*"))  //checks for drive letter and colon
     path = path.split(":")[1];   //get everything after colon
```